# How to inherit asp.net ApplicationUser classes in order to create "user Types" or Roles?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, inheritance

So I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and EF and I want to create a "user type" and by that I mean a division of users by using the properties of the generated users in the default authentication.

so here's my Model Class:

```
public class Student : ApplicationUser
{

    [Required]
    public string firstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string lastName { get; set; }

}
```

As you can see I inherited the default ApplicationUser Object thinking that my Student Object was a type of Student which was true after looking at the database mofications Done after my Database-Update:

```
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ADD [firstName] [nvarchar](max)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ADD [lastName] [nvarchar](max)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ADD [Discriminator] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

As you can see it added my Students attributes and used a discriminator to differentiate between a regular user and a Student BUT after Scaffolding and going to localhost/Students, there's all the "RegularUseer" attributes on the list, here's my screen for more details.

Screen Capture of the Get: Students result

[image]

as You can see in the image Above I have my passwordHash listed and bunch of other attributes that I don't want displayed.

How can I inherit the ApplicationUser Class Correctly?
thanks in advance

[EDIT]

After some more research I found a workaround this to do it properly but I find a it a little junkie I added a method to the startup.cs file in my project where I create the roles (User Types) using Identity Role here it is.

```
 public void CreateRoles()
    {
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
        //var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(context));
        var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

        //Create SuperAdmin Role
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("SuperAdmin"))
        {

            var role = new IdentityRole("SuperAdmin");
            roleManager.Create(role);
            context.Roles.Add(role);
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { Email = "admin@email.com", UserName = "adminName" };
            //userManager.Create<ApplicationUser>(user, "superAdminPassword");
            var newuser = userManager.Create(user, "myPassword@123");
            if (newuser.Succeeded)
            {
                userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "SuperAdmin");
                throw new Exception("it succeded");

            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Hello World");
            }


        }
        else
        {
            if(userManager.FindByEmail("admin@email.com") == null)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser() { Email = "admin@email.com", UserName = "adminName" };
                var newuser = userManager.Create(user, "myPassword@123");
                if(newuser.Succeeded)
                {
                    userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "SuperAdmin");
                    context.Users.Add(user);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

            }
        }

        //Create Admin Role
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
        {
            var role = new IdentityRole("Admin");
            roleManager.Create(role);
        }

        //Create User Role
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("User"))
        {
            var role = new IdentityRole("User");
            roleManager.Create(role);
        }
    }
```

I added some Exceptions for testing purposes and it worked, My roles are created and I checked my table and that user I created with the SuperAdmin Role is in the Database with the adequate properties, the only issue here is that I can't Login through the application and the displayed error was "Tentative de connexion non valide." so I checked the Login ActionResult here it is:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // Ceci ne comptabilise pas les échecs de connexion pour le verrouillage du compte
        // Pour que les échecs de mot de passe déclenchent le verrouillage du compte, utilisez shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Tentative de connexion non valide.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

And after exploring this ActionResult my SignInstatus is SignInStatus.Failure as you can verify in the code above Even though I can see the account I'm trying to log-in in the database

Comment: I would have something like UserBase which would have a UserType property.  Inherit from that and set its property for each user type Student:UserBase and set the base.UserType property.  Then when you pull the user from db just check the property.  This is the simplest way and there are countless others.

Comment: What you're saying is actually doable and correct, but I'm willing to use Entity Framework and it's Code First method and use scaffolding to be more productive... if I have to pull from the db myself than that would render Entity Framework useless... but thanks for the modeling tip, might use it in a case where I would prefer do most of the work by myself